# Keyboard shortcuts JQUERY - Command+S, Control+S

Tags: jquery, keyboard, ckeditor

I have a text editor on my site and I want users to be able to use keyboard shortcuts to save, just like they would in Microsoft Word:

- For the Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- For the PC: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

What is the best way to accomplish this in jQuery? Also, this will be used to save content in CKEditor, which uses an iFrame, not sure if that's an issue or not.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.keystrokeHandler.html

Class CKEDITOR.keystrokeHandler

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that CKEditor has [built in hotkey functionality](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.keystrokes)?

It's pretty straightforward to implement: You set up an array `keystrokes` in your config array; take the example array from the link above; Look up the keystroke for "S"; and amend the array by an entry for it, and the appropriate CKEditor command. I can't test it right now but this is what it *should* look like. You may need to look up the appropriate command for the "save" operation you want to execute.

```
... your config array .....

CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes = 
[
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 121 /*F10*/, 'toolbarFocus' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 122 /*F11*/, 'elementsPathFocus' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 121 /*F10*/, 'contextMenu' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90 /*Z*/, 'undo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 89 /*Y*/, 'redo' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 90 /*Z*/, 'redo' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76 /*L*/, 'link' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /*B*/, 'bold' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73 /*I*/, 'italic' ],
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 /*U*/, 'underline' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 83 /*S*/, 'save' ],

    [ CKEDITOR.ALT + 109 /*-*/, 'toolbarCollapse' ]
];
```

Comment: Yes, but there is not documentation on how to implement it?

Comment: What about the COMMAND key for mac?

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, to capture CMD-s, assign an event handler to the editor like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].on('key', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.data.keyCode)
    //cmd-s - save
    if (evt.data.keyCode == 1114195) {
        evt.cancel();
        save();
    }    
});
```

In my example, I'm calling my `save()` function.